# How can I lookup a turtle by label and get its WHO value?

Tags: netlogo

## Problem

I use this getter-function to lookup a turtle by its label. But now I need to refactor the function to return its `who` value instead of the turtle itself. My code below is getting the following error message.

```
OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or turtle but got NOBODY instead.
```

## Attempts to solve the problem

I had the following code that correctly performed a turtle lookup.

```
to-report get-user [user-name]
  report one-of users with [ label = user-name ]
end
```

But when I tried to get the who of that turtle I keep geting `nobody`.

```
to-report get-user [user-name]
  report [who] of one-of users with [ label = user-name ]
end
```

Is there a better way of going about finding the who of a turtle, given a string and performing a lookup on the label? Or am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me no problem- are you sure your string values match? If you input a value and that label doesn't exist, `users with [ label = user-name ]` will return `nobody`- you would need to accommodate for that- for example:

```
to setup
  ca
  let names [ "John" "Jacob" "Jingle" "Heimer"  ]
  crt 4 [
    setxy ( who + 1 ) * 2 ( who + 1 ) * 2
    set label first names
    set names but-first names
  ]
  reset-ticks  
end

to go
  foreach [ "John" "Jacob" "Jingle" "Heimer" "Schmidt" ] [
    nm ->
    print get-user nm
  ]

end

to-report get-user [ user-name ]
  if any? turtles with [ label = user-name ] [
    report [who] of one-of turtles with [ label = user-name ]
  ]
  report "USER DOES NOT EXIST"
end
```

Comment: You are right, my code was working correctly, I had an issue somewhere else.